# Event of browser crash in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, events, browser, crash

I want to execute a action on the event of browser crash in asp.net. I want to destroy the item added in the cart and revert back to the original state of the application and database if the browser crashes.

How can I do this?

Comment: The server can not know if the browser has crashed or the user closed the browser or the power went off.

Comment: I dont think it is possible, but i would like to hear if such a task can be accomplished.

Comment: The best bet might be to attach to the user session ended event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, not possible, due to several factors.

1) the net is stateless, that is to say that the web server has no idea about the web browser, other than that it requested something. After it's serviced the request, it has no way of communicating with the browser.

2) the browser has the same issue. Once it's asked the server for the content and got it, that's it. If the user closes their browser, or lets their session time out, or if the browser crashes, the server doesn't know about it, and the browser doesn't tell it.

3) if the browser crashes, it's crashed, so it can't send any information anywhere, on account of the fact that it isn't working any more.

You can hook into the session_end event, which will fire when a user's session ends (a session ends when the user hasn't asked for anything for a certain period of time, 20 minutes is the default for this), however there's no way to tell WHY the session ended. the users browser may have crashed, they may have closed their browser, or they may have got bored and gone to another site.

Normally I wouldn't update the application state until after a user checks out, so the basket would be the only thing I'd need to delete. To do that I set a datetime column on my cart table, and update it every time the cart is updated. I then run a scheduled task on the database every day that deletes all baskets that are older than the amount of time I keep the baskets for.